# Cisco SNMP設定で取得するSVがv2cで出力する側がv1の場合でも取得出来ますか

Tags: snmp

現在SNMP v2cにてトラップ取得を行っているのですが、
これをv1のSNMP設定機器から出力した場合もトラップ取得は出来ますか？